# Page not loading at localhost:8080

Tags: python, localhost, computer-vision, simplecv

I'm trying to learn [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/), and in it's tutorials it says to display an image in the browser, use

```
img.show(type="browser")
```

Whenever I do this, my browser leads me to localhost:8080, and the page will not load. How can I start a simple server in Python so that the page will load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `import webbrowser` from the shell. If it fails you need to install the [library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) (`pip install` or `easy_install`).